# Detect the presence of menubar from Firefox extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla

I've written a Firefox extension , that need to know whether menu-bar is present or not. and also need to be notified hide/show of menu-bar  ?

How do i do this ?
Please help me

Comment: What have you tried and why did it fail? Did you had any errors? Do you have code to show what you have tried to do so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `autohide` attribute of the `toolbar-menubar`.

```
var menubarPresent = document.getElementById("toolbar-menubar").getAtttribute("autohide") === "false" ? true : false
```

You can get notified of changes through a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver)

Comment: Can you eloberate the above Answer?